# How can I query on the same table & get result in 2 columns

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I have this table with the following data

```
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Owner | closeDate | stage | value |  
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Abc   | 1-1-2017  | won   |  1000 |  
| Abc   | 31-1-2017 | won   |  2000 |  
| Abc   | 3-1-2017  | lost  |  1000 |  
| Abc   |  1-2-2017 | won   |  5000 |  
| Def   | 1-2-2017  | won   |  3000 |  
| Def   | 28-2-2017 | won   |  4000 |  
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

I am aiming for a result like this where it groups the total value for each owner per month for only won stage

```
+-------+----------+----------+
| Owner | JanValue | FebValue |  
+-------+----------+----------+
| Abc   |     3000 |     5000 |  
| Def   |        0 |     7000 |  
+-------+----------+----------+
```

I have tried this query but the results is getting in the record

```
  SELECT Owner, sum(value) ,datename(month, closedate) as 'month'
  FROM Table1
   where closedate between '2017/01/1' and '2017/01/31' and stage='won'
GROUP BY Owner,datename(month, closedate)

UNION ALL


  SELECT Owner, sum(value) ,datename(month, closedate) as 'month'
  FROM Table1
   where closedate between '2017/02/1' and '2017/02/28' and stage='won'
GROUP BY Owner,datename(month, closedate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a pivot query, this time involving the month of the close date:

```
SELECT
    Owner,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, closeDate) = 1 THEN value END) AS JanValue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, closeDate) = 2 THEN value END) AS FebValue,
    ...
FROM Table1
WHERE
    stage = 'won' AND
    DATEPART(year, closeDate) = 2017
GROUP BY
    Owner;
```

Note that this approach gets stretched a bit thin when you want to consider having a monthly report across many years.  In that case, you might want to use dynamic SQL to do the pivot.  But, in such a case having so many months across columns would not be the most readable output IMO.

Comment: Yes it works very well, however, if I want to get the total sum for the value in january, I should use Sum instead of Max  in the query?

Comment: @sara Yes, just replace `MAX` with `SUM` (I have already done this).  Maybe I didn't read your data closely enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Dynamic result

```
SELECT
  *
  FROM
  (
      SELECT
        *
        FROM
        (
          SELECT
            Owner,
            CloseDate = DATENAME(month,CAST(CloseDate AS DATE)),
            Val
            FROM Table1
        )T
        PIVOT
        (
          SUM(VAL)
          FOR CloseDate IN
          (
            [January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],[December]
          )
        )Pvt
  )Q
```

This will be your sample result

[image: Sample Result]

for the following input

[image: Sampel Input]

The result is **without filtering the Stage**. You can give it in the following select

```
SELECT
            Owner,
            CloseDate = DATENAME(month,CAST(CloseDate AS DATE)),
            Val
            FROM Table1
where <Your Conditions>
```